# How to set Right Toggle Button in Action Bar?

Tags: android

I have an Action Bar. It has two drawers coming from left and right.

For the left, I'm using the Action Bar Toggle button on the top left as shown in the image below. Can I put that toggle button in the right side too?

I can use a custom linear layout view (ImageView - EditText - ImageView) to add it to the `getActionBar.setCustomView()` method and implement click listeners on the imageview's to show drawers.

My question is, does android provide a right toggle button like the left?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your .xml file and Java code.

### First Step

Let start with your .xml file.

**Code**

First `FrameLayout`: represent to action-bar, note we have `ImageView` called `drawer_indicator` and it's our right toggle.

Second `FrameLayout`: represent our fragment containers.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    
        <!-- Action-bar looking view -->
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_dimen"
            android:background="@color/blue" >
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_indicator"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_dimen"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_dimen"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_selector"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/indicator_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_dimen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:text="@string/tests"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    
        </FrameLayout>
  <!-- Action-bar Ends -->



    <!-- Drawer Layout -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    
         <!-- our Fragment Content-->

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_gray"
                android:gravity="center" />
    <!-- slide menu  android:layout_gravity="end" to make it come from right-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"    
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
    
               
             <!-- drawer list-->
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/DrawerList"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

### Second Step

Get [DrawerArrowDrawable](https://github.com/ChrisRenke/DrawerArrowDrawable/tree/master/app/src/main/java/chrisrenke/drawerarrowdrawable) from this link

```
private DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrowDrawable;
    private float offset;
    private boolean flipped;
    ListView DrawerList;
    DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // to make activity full screen 
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         // it must before setContentView
            setContentView(R.layout.home_view);
            
            // drawer list
            DrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DrawerList);

           // drawer item list
            ArrayList<DrawerItem> Items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
            // fill arraylist 
            Items.add(new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.tests),
                    R.drawable.test));
            // drawer adapter 
            DrawerAdapter adapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, Items);
     // set adapter to our drawer list
            DrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    
             // attach listener to drawer list 
            DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
    
                    // handle select item here
                }
            });
             // initialize our drawer layout 
            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           // right toggle button 
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_indicator);
            final Resources resources = getResources();
           // its custom class 
            drawerArrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(resources);
            drawerArrowDrawable.setStrokeColor(resources
                    .getColor(R.color.light_gray));
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawerArrowDrawable);
    
            drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    offset = slideOffset;
    
                    // Sometimes slideOffset ends up so close to but not quite 1 or 0.
                    if (slideOffset >= .995) {
                        flipped = true;
                        drawerArrowDrawable.setFlip(flipped);
                    } else if (slideOffset <= .005) {
                        flipped = false;
                        drawerArrowDrawable.setFlip(flipped);
                    }
    
                    drawerArrowDrawable.setParameter(offset);
                }
            });
    
            
    // attach listener to toggle image view 
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                    openDrawer();
                }
            });
    }
```

I hope it be clear to you.